# How to get key=value insert format dump file?

Tags: mysql

I need to get dump insert statements as: `key=value,key=value,key=value` instead of `(key,key,key) values (value,value,value,)`

Is it possible with mysqldump or any other tools?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the `INSERT ... SET` syntax.

Comment: @shmosel correct assumption

Comment: why would this be needed?